# How to auto select youtube-dl format in C#

Tags: c#, string, bash, youtube-dl

I saw code in this community and try to use in my case. All work perfectly for simple cases like:

Download `youtube-dl -f 299+140 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oy7jsE4HVaw`

But, I am trying to grab the

> -f bestvideo[height<=?1080]+bestaudio/best

and merge, and this command some times return a 720p quality video instead of 1080p or not the best 1080p.

After reading the [documentation](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#format-selection) I can make the `"if case"` of the quality using "/". but the code on the "+" skip and download only the first video not the the audio.

I solve this by including `","` and download the audio and video normal, but it doesn't merge.

I have to try put at the end bestaudio+bestvideo and its returns:"video is already merged", but don't delete the others archives and I can not see the results.

I thought of reading the output string, such as 1080 and file size (out of e.Data), but no result. I don't know how to do it. If I can take this output it could be more easy for me to make a simple program that chooses the audio and video and merge.

Is there any other way to do it?

[The code that I am using](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Yc3rPhamlspfmUqljs9JxVHNcx1RDVvJ) (i don't know why I had a hard time copy and paste the code here and still came out with errors):

Comment: It's not really "in C#" as you are just starting a process in C#, but you're using the console application. And in which cases is a 720p video chosen? Does a 1080p video exist in this cases? Because otherwise it's obvious that it can't be chosen...

Comment: @csabinho yes, i'm starting the process in C#, but a can also monitore de output (e.Data), i belive... I want, if possible, stract a stringe or some flag that can start a "if case" in C#, and in the future make a ide. Like, if a read 720p (string) a can skipe, if it's 1080p a can choise and add another if for fps preference. I want that becouse the basic comands of documentation is not helping me. The 1080p video exist and the program download a 1080p of worst quality not the best 1080 or 720p, like the code a post here "height<=?1080". If not possible last hope is go direcly in github program

Comment: Why don't you just use Python? The program was written in Python and has a library in this language. What you are doing is something semi-shellscripting in C#.

Comment: @csabinho  like a AutoIt (was my idea)... but, if the only resource is that, i can try to look at  the source code.  :(

Comment: I loss two pc... and i don't use this program any more... but i did catch good results using mpv and yotube-dl to output what i want. Is was't the best, but worked. Now days i use a aplication on the bowser call h264ify and this do miracles on my divices. using Opera + "add to opera"+ h264ify low my requeriments for playvideos on youtube and now don't have probleman.